# Where is bin file located after installing Neo4j with .dmg file?

Tags: neo4j, bin

I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.5, and I installed Neo4j using neo4j-community_macos_3_2_1.dmg. I chose the location of database as ~/Documents/default.graphdb when I was prompted, and Neo4j works fine at http://127.0.0.1:7474/browser/. However, I am not able to locate the .bin file that is usually located in the untarred installation folder if I downloaded Neo4j as a Unix console application tar.gz file. Where is the .bin file in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the application package itself, an app in OS X is actually a package structure you can explore.

Right-click on the app, choose Show Package Contents, and check the folder contents. It's under `Contents/Resources/app/bin`.